# Accessing class fields from a nested class

Tags: c#, class, nested

What is the best way to access fields from a nested class?

```
class FirstClass
{
    public int FirstClassField;
    public FirstClass()
    {
        this.FirstClassField = 5;
    }
    class SecondNestedClass
    {
        int SecondClassField;
        public SecondNestedClass()
        {
            FirstClassField = 6;
        }
    }
}
```

The error:

> An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'FirstClass.FirstClassField'

The goal is to be able to use and modify `FirstClass` fields from the Nested class.

For my purposes, the first class is a form

```
public partial class MyForm : Form
```

And passing a reference of `MyForm` is not possible since it is readonly.

Any ideas?

Comment: Just pass reference to parent class to child class constructor: new SecondNestedClass(this).

Comment: C# nested types don't work like Java's. If you want the nested type to be able to access an instance member of its containing type, you have to pass the instance reference explicitly yourself. I.e. accessing instance members in this scenario works exactly like any other scenario in C#: you have to have the instance reference and use it when accessing the instance member. See the marked duplicate for additional discussion on the topic.

Answer (score 0):

The nested class is just a nested *type*, nothing like a nested *instance*. So if you create an instance of `SecondNestedClass`, there is no instance of `FirstClass` involved. So for which `FirstClass` instance do you want to set `FirstClassField`?

`SecondNestedClass` and `FirstClass` are completely different and independent types. `FirstClassField` is *not* a member of `SecondNestedClass`.

The only difference to non-nested types is that an instance of `SecondNestedClass` is allowed to access `private` fields of an instance of `FirstClass`. But you still need an instance at all to access its fields.

How to solve this depends on what you *actually* are trying to achieve. You could consider providing an instance of `FirstClass` to the constructor of `SecondNestedClass`:

```
public SecondNestedClass(FirstClass first)
{
    first.FirstClassField = 6;
}
```

Comment: The issue is I would need that instance to be a reference to the class, and that is not possible with a readonly parameter

Comment: I guess you need to explain a little broader what you are really trying to achieve, because this does not make much sense yet. There is no such thing as a "reference to a class", only _instances_ of classes are referenced. Again,  if you have an instance of `SecondNestedClass` there is no instance of `FirstClass` that is associated with it in any way. These two types are (almost) completely independent. If you'd explain what you actually want to achieve, there may be better solutions than nested types.

Comment: editing........

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/Enoz/InfiniPad/blob/master/InfiniPad/EditorEx.cs#L67-L87) and [Here](https://github.com/Enoz/InfiniPad/blob/master/InfiniPad/EditorEx.cs#L99-L115) is an example of what I'm trying to organize well. I'm trying to organize it a bit better so I don't need to have a bunch of the same "if" statements in each method, but rather just have a class for each condition and use polymorphism to run each case in each method. (if that makes sense)